# Number of ways to select a subset of the set $ \{1, 2, . . . , 200 \}$ in such a way that it contains the same number of even and odd elements.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Select a subset of the set $ \{1, 2, . . . , 200 \}$ in such a way that it contains the same number of even and odd elements. In how many ways can this be done?

My solution:

To ensure that a subset has an equal number of even and odd numbers we need to choose $k$ even numbers (out of $100$) and choose $k$ odd numbers (out of $100$).

The number of ways to choose $k$ even numbers from $100$ is ${{100}\choose{k}}$ and the number of ways to choose $k$ odd numbers from $100$ is ${{100}\choose{k}}$ as well.

So, the correct number seems to be:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{100} {{100}\choose{k}}^2 = {{200}\choose{100}}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Your reasoning seems okay to me to $\sum_{k=0}^{100}{100 \choose k}^2$.  But how do you jump to $\sum_{k=0}^{100}{100 \choose k}^2={200 \choose 100}$?

Comment: https://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3/sec_comb-proofs.html, exmaple 1.4.7.

Comment: I thought that it is some well known combinatorial equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct, and the last step uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Here's an alternative approach to see that the count is $\binom{200}{100}$.  Let $E=\{2,,4,\dots,200\}$, take any $100$-subset $S$ of $\{1,\dots,200\}$, keep the even numbers in $S$, and take the complement of the odd numbers in $S$, yielding a subset with $|S \cap E|$ even numbers and $100-(100-|S \cap E|)=|S \cap E|$ odd numbers. Every good subset arises uniquely this way.

Comment: lovely argument